# what has changed in the set before and after

Tags: algorithm

This is an interview question: You are given two arrays: before: {3, 3, 5, 8, 1} and after: {5, 3, 2, 4}. Determine what numbers were removed/added from/to the ‘before’ array in order to obtain ‘after’.

I can think of using two hashmaps for each lists with  as the  and comparing each of them to tell whether each element has been added or removed.

Can someone think of a better approach or give an alternate solution (with better time/space completixy) for this one?

Comment: This is related to a well know problem, [Approximate String Matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)

Comment: Does order matter? I.e. is `{3,5}` the same as `{5,3}` or was there a removal + addition?

Comment: @Dukeling: No, the order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could store each list in bags then find the change in occurencies of each item type in the bags.

Here's some Python:

```
>>> # Original data
... l1, l2 = [3,3,5,8,1], [5,3,2,4]
>>> # Pythons Counter class in also known as a bag
... from collections import Counter
>>> c1, c2 = Counter(l1), Counter(l2)
>>> # Quick calculation
... diffs = {item:(c2[item] - c1[item]) for item in set(c1) | set(c2)}
>>> diffs
{1: -1, 2: 1, 3: -1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 8: -1}
>>> # Or if you want it wordy
... for item in sorted(set(c1) | set(c2)):
...     print('Item %i changed its occurences by %2i'
...           % (item, c2[item] - c1[item]))
... 
Item 1 changed its occurences by -1
Item 2 changed its occurences by  1
Item 3 changed its occurences by -1
Item 4 changed its occurences by  1
Item 5 changed its occurences by  0
Item 8 changed its occurences by -1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution discussed in one of the above threads would be O(n+m) n,m being size of the 2 arrays since you need to iterate thru the entire length of both arrays in worst case. A possible improvement would be to perform a binary search of each element in the 2nd array in the 1st and then remove it from the first array if it is found.If not add it to the  array.After all iterations, add the remaining elements in the first array to the final array list.The time complexity would be O(mlogn)

```
function binaryIndexOf(searchElement, searchArray) {
'use strict';
var minIndex = 0;
var maxIndex = searchArray.length - 1;
var currentIndex;
var currentElement;

while (minIndex <= maxIndex) {
    currentIndex = (minIndex + maxIndex) / 2 | 0;
    currentElement = searchArray[currentIndex];

    if (currentElement < searchElement) {
        minIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    }
    else if (currentElement > searchElement) {
        maxIndex = currentIndex - 1;
    }
    else {
        return currentIndex;
    }
}

return -1;
}
var before = [3, 3, 5, 8, 1];
var after = [5, 3, 2, 4];
var intsort = function (a, b) {
return a - b
};
var i;
var resultArray = [];
var elementIndex;
before.sort(intsort);
after.sort(intsort); 
for (i = 0; i < after.length; i++) {
 elementIndex = binaryIndexOf(after[i], before);
 if (elementIndex != -1)
        before.splice(elementIndex, 1);
 else
        resultArray.push(after[i]);
 }
j = 0;
while (j < before.length) { 
  resultArray.push(before[j++]); 
}
console.log("result=" + resultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you suggest (using two hashmaps) is the best possible result, i.e. O(n+m), because you will always need to visit each element of each array at-least once.

Here is my implementation for C# to demonstrate the concept:

```
var b = new [] {3, 3, 5, 8, 1}.ToLookup(k => k);
var a = new [] {5, 3, 2, 4}.ToLookup(k => k);

b.Select(k => k.Key)
 .Concat(a.Select(k => k.Key))
 .Distinct()
 .ToDictionary(k => k, v => (a.Contains(v) ? a[v].Count() : 0) - (b.Contains(v) ? b[v].Count() : 0))
 .Dump(); // linqpad
```

I've used lots of linq to keep it concise; would likely be more efficient to re-write with the equivalent in loops and HashSets.